# JS/CSS Transform property not being modified

Tags: javascript, html, css

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/jsmrcaga/pen/ZogpYx?editors=0010)

Hello everyone,

I'm having a little hard time figuring out why the JS on the codepen won't work. Applying `element.style.transform` directly works perfectly, however when applied via `mousemove` nothing happens.

Modifying `transform` for any other css property works as expected. I've also tested `webkitTransform` on chrome to no avail.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, a semi-colon prevented that and troubled you! Remove semi-colon from the template:

```
let transform = `rotateX(${degs.x}deg) rotateY(${degs.y}deg) perspective(1000px) scale3d(1.06, 1.06, 1.06)`;
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XqvjYG

Comment: Oh my god, can't believe that was it... thanks a lot KK!